# combine value from two tables for a given username

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement where I have two database tables users and users_custom with following columns.

**users table**

```
userkey,
username,
first name, 
last name,
employee id,
status
```

**users_custom table**

```
userkey,
custom_property_1,
custom_property_2,
custom_property_3,
custom_property_4
```

**userkey in users_custom is the foreign key.**

I have been provided with value of username

How do I construct a query that would combine values from both the table for a single user whose username is available.

Any helps or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN users_custom ON users.userkey = users_custom.userkey WHERE users.username = "name";
```

here name is the value of username provided to you

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you just have to `JOIN` those tables on the users' ids.
Sorry if the syntax isn't correct as I'm more used to SQL Server and SQLite, but the line of thought is the same:

```
SELECT *
FROM users_table LEFT JOIN users_custom_table ON users_table.userkey = users_custom_table.id
WHERE users_table.username= (the desired username...)
```

[More info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) on JOINs.

Comment: Thanks user1987392 abd Sid M!!